# How to convert string value returned from oracle apex 20.1 multiselect item into comma separated numbers array

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a multi select enabled select list. I want to use all the selected ids inside an IN () operator in pl/sql query. Selected values are returned as below,

```
"1","5","4"
```

I want to use em as numbers as below,

```
1,5,4
```

My query is like,

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET EMPSTAT = 'Active' WHERE EMPID IN (:P500_EMPIDS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping everyone.Please check this and tell me if anything is wrong. I found a solution as below,

```
DECLARE
l_selected APEX_APPLICATION_GLOBAL.VC_ARR2;
BEGIN
    l_selected := APEX_UTIL.STRING_TO_TABLE(:P500_EMPIDS);
    FOR i in 1 .. l_selected.count LOOP 
        UPDATE EMPLYEE SET EMPSTATUS = 'ACTIVE' WHERE EMPID = to_number(l_selected(i));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API [apex_string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/APEX_STRING.html) for this. If you want to use the IN operator you'll have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE because you cannot use a concatenated string in an IN operator.
Instead what you could do is the following:

```
DECLARE
  l_array           apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
  l_array := apex_string.split(p_str  => :P500_EMPIDS, p_sep  => ':');
   FOR i IN 1..l_array.count LOOP
     UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET EMPSTAT = 'Active' WHERE EMPID = l_array(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Explanation: convert the colon separated list of ids to a table of varchar2, then loop through the elements of that table.

Note that I'm using ":" as a separator, that is what apex uses for multi selects. If you need "," then change code above accordingly.

Comment: I got an error saying "PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification" when use "l_array.(i)" in where close.

Comment: should i replace "p_sep" with "," ..? Am so sorry am a noob to this.. :)

Comment: Actually it's not a string value, string value is like "1,2,3" but what am getting from the select list is like "1","2","3" .. Like an string array..

Comment: Fixed - there was a typo (I had l_array.(i) which should be l_array(i)). Could it be that in the select list definition you are enclosing the return values in double quotes ? I would modify that instead of cleaning them up in the back end code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the employee table:

```
SQL> select * from employee;

     EMPID EMPSTAT
---------- --------
         1 Inactive
         2 Inactive
         4 Inactive
         5 Inactive

SQL>
```

This is a way to split comma-separated values into **rows** (not into a list of values you'd use in `IN`!). Note that:

- line #3: `REPLACE` function replaces double quotes with an empty string
- line #3: then it is split into rows using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with help of hierarchical query

---

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '"1","5","4"' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(replace(col, '"', ''), '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1;

VAL
--------------------
1
5
4

SQL>
```

Usually multiselect items have colon-separated values, e.g. `1:5:4`. If that's really the case, regular expression would look like this:

```
regexp_substr(col, '[^:]+', 1, level) val
```

Use it in Apex as:

```
update employee e set
  e.empstat = 'Active'
  where e.empid in 
    (select regexp_substr(replace(:P1_ITEM, '"', ''), '[^,]+', 1, level)
     from dual
     connect by level <= regexp_count(:P1_ITEM, ',') + 1
    );
```

Result is:

```
3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from employee order by empid;

     EMPID EMPSTAT
---------- --------
         1 Active
         2 Inactive
         4 Active
         5 Active

SQL>
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use `apex_string` directly within an update statement, so the answer of `Koen Lostrie` could be modified to not need a loop:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET EMPSTAT = 'Active'
WHERE EMPID IN (
    select to_number(trim('"' from column_value))
    from table(apex_string.split(:P500_EMPIDS,','))
);
```

Testcase:

```
with cte1 as (
    select '"1","2","3"' as x from dual
)
select to_number(trim('"' from column_value))
from table(apex_string.split((select x from cte1),','))
```